# Handle arrays with undefined size

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I'm working on a 1D produceal generator. Im using chunks to oly load the current content. My problem is that I'm using a array undefined size to store data. If I would use a ArrayList it would create a new array to expand it if needed, but does that not create garbage?

Would it be faster to use a buffer array whit a large size, store the data in to it. Create based on the length a new array for the chunk and cooy the data?

Comment: What do you mean "create garbage?" As in additional things for the GC to collect? Pre-allocated space that is not used?

Comment: Yes for the GC to collect. The problem is the size could be from 10 to 1000 or even more.

Comment: If you need dynamic/variable space, then using a collection like `ArrayList` is probably preferable over an array.  As for wasted space when the JVM decides to increase the size, there is no avoiding this as you asked for variable size.

Comment: What about buffering the data and the copy it? If an ArrayList does allocate more space it does copy the array aswell.

Comment: @DarioKowalski I would recommend using an ArrayList but if you have a minimum size you would expect, instantiate your ArrayList to that size to prevent needless list growth.

Comment: If you need to store primitives, I hope you are (or you'll become very soon) aware that `int != java.lang.Integer`, the `sizeof(Integer) > sizeof(int)` and there is a thing called `boxing / unboxing` of primitive types. Also, that there are a number of 3rd party collections (which dynamically expand/shrink) to deal with collections of primitives (a thing that high perf computing and high frequency traders prefer to use): something like [HPPC](https://github.com/carrotsearch/hppc) or [Koloboke](https://github.com/leventov/Koloboke) or [fastutil](http://fastutil.di.unimi.it/)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't know the exact size of the array in advance, you are going to create garbage either way. You'll either overallocate the size of the array or end up having to allocate a new array, copy the values from the old one and dump the old reference. Either way, garbage, and that's how an ArrayList works internally. It's literally just a `List` wrapper around an array.

FWIW, I think you are way overthinking the issue. An array of objects is just an array of references. None of the items in the array actually do more than hold enough space to reference a memory address until you initialize them.